# Excel - Add Hyperlinks to another cell based on a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a number of identical workbooks which each contain a data table. I need to add either a separate "Explanations" tab, which contains a definition of each column, or add a comment to each column. I'd prefer the Explanations method, and using Hyperlinks. My data table might looks like this, but with a lot more columns. And in each file, it'll have a different set of columns:

Data Table:

[image: Data Table]

My Explanations tab might look like this, again a different set of explanations in each workbook, but column A will identically match one of the data table columns:

Explanations Tab:

[image: Explanations Tab]

Is there a way, with formulas alone, to HyperLink the column headings in Data Table to the proper cells in the Explanations tab? Or to include the Explanation in a comment?

Or should I resort to VBA? My company is generally hesitant to using any VBA, but I could probably figure this out quickly (or find an identical example online).

Comment: How do you mean hyperlink with formulas? What is the expected result? You can hyperlink to the explanation, but that seems weird. You can put the Explanation in the "mouse-over-dialouge-box" of a hyperlink too.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem right you're trying to create hyperlink for the headers for each workbook, pointing to the same explanations tab in each one of them. I think you can do that only with formulas if you combine Hyperlink and Address.

Supposing that you create a worksheet named "Explanations" in each of your workbooks, you could write a function in the headers that would look like this: "**=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(1,1,,,"Explanations"),"Employee ID")**". So this function would point to cell A1 where supposedly the Employee ID explanation would be.

If you don't want to display the formulas in the headers you could hide them using worksheet protection, so first you select all cells, press Ctrl+1, go to the protection tab, unmark "Locked", then close the format cells box, then select the headers and do the same thing but in the protection tab mark "Hidden". Finally go to the Review tab in the ribbon and click on "Protect Sheet", you can leave it without a password to unprotect it if you want, and you can mark everything if you want other people to edit. After that they wont be able to see the formula of the hyperlink.

I recommend if you're going to do a lot of workbooks based on this to save the first one (without data inserted) as a template.

Hope it helped.